# Python 3.7.9 , combine print from if/else to print on one line

Tags: python-3.x, function, printing

New to python so I guess this is a newbie question.

I have a simple program that take input (a number) from the user and send it to my function that converts the input to it's binary form. The code works but the function prints on a new line for each 1 or 0 which gives a vertical output. I want to change how the output is printed so that it prints horisontal, on one line. I have one restriction, I can't use "return" in the function. I hope someone can help me with this!

Current output form:

[image: Current output form]

Looking for output like this:

[image: Looking for output like this]

Code-section where the function is called:

```
if inputvalue < 256:
        print("The number", inputvalue,"fits in one byte and in binary form: ");
        dec2bin(inputvalue, 8)
        
    
elif inputvalue > 256:
        print("The number", inputvalue, "fits in one word (16-bit) and in binary form: ");
        dec2bin(inputvalue, 16)
```

The function:

```
def dec2bin(value, number_of_digits):

while number_of_digits > 0:
    
    binaryvalue = 2**(number_of_digits -1)
    
    if value >= binaryvalue:
        print("1");
        value = value - binaryvalue;
    
    else:
        print("0");
        
    number_of_digits = number_of_digits -1;
```

Comment: you can specify how your printed string ends with `print("1", end='')` and `print("0", end='')` respectively

Comment: Thank you! However, that only partly solved the problem. The 1:s and 0:s are now together but still printed on a separate line.

Comment: You can specify `end` values for your other `print` statements. However, I'd advise to not print from the function but instead return a value and then print the returned value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might rather use a variable in the `dec2bin` function to build the result and print it once it's complete.

```
def dec2bin(value, number_of_digits):

    result = ""

    while number_of_digits > 0:

        binaryvalue = 2**(number_of_digits -1)

        if value >= binaryvalue:
            result += "1"
            value = value - binaryvalue

        else:
            result += "0"
    
        number_of_digits = number_of_digits -1

    print(result)
```

Or maybe more common approch - let the function return the result and print it outside.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I also thought about the use of a variable to store the result and then print the variable but I didn't know how to write it. I will try your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to my comment, and also handling any case (your code wouldn't work for `inputvalue > 65535`), you can use a formatted string:

```
import math

def dec2bin(value, number_of_digits):
    result = ''
    while number_of_digits > 0:
        binaryvalue = 2**(number_of_digits -1)
        if value >= binaryvalue:
            result += '1'
            value = value - binaryvalue     
        else:
            result += '0'           
        number_of_digits = number_of_digits -1
    
    return result


inputvalue = -1
while inputvalue < 0:
    try:
        inputvalue = int(input("Please enter a positive integer: "))
    except:
        pass

nb_bit = 8
if inputvalue == 0:
    pass
else:
    while nb_bit <= math.log(inputvalue, 2):
        nb_bit += 8
        
print(f"The number {inputvalue} fits in {nb_bit} bit and in binary form: {dec2bin(inputvalue, nb_bit)}")
```

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion! I guess I should have included more information about the restrictions and goals of function of my project,. The program was not required to handle any case, just specifik ones.